# Are "Is [Software] Legit?" Questions On Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a new question asking if a site claiming to have a free download of Adobe CS6 is legitimate: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19970/is-this-software-genuine

Are such questions considered on topic? My first thought was that it wasn't but I haven't spent enough time on this site to know one way or the other. Should this question be answered or should it be flagged as Off Topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding this particular example:

> I saw this website and couldn't believe that it was genuine: [URL redacted]

That's pretty blatant spam.

Regarding “is this download site genuine” in general, I don't see how it fits our scope. The closest way I can think of to make it match is that it's asking for recommendations of a download website, which [is off-topic](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-i-ask-for-recommended-websites). And even that is a stretch, it's more of a “rate this website”.

Regarding “is this application ‘legit’?” (as in does it do what's advertised, is it not malware), that would fall under [Can I ask if a particular software will fit my needs?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/can-i-ask-if-a-particular-software-will-fit-my-needs), for which our policy is to change the question to ask about said needs and include a suggestion about which not enough is known to make an answer. If the question doesn't explain the asker's needs, [it isn't suitable](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I assumed the link wasn't legit but hadn't flagged it for spam. I spend so much time at StackOverflow I'm not used to the spam that isn't someone screaming a phone number for printer support for 500 lines.